# Antlr4 (java) tries to match all input to first token

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4, intellij-plugin

my antlr (I'm using IntelliJ plugin) matches all my input to the first expression in my parser rule, which obviously causes an error.

Simple example:

```
grammar test;
rule  : WORD '+' WORD;
WORD  : [a-z]+;
```

Now testing:

input = 'faefae' gets me:

> line 1:6 mismatched input '' expecting '+'

(so far it makes sense)

input = 'faefae+':

> line 1:0 mismatched input 'faefae+' expecting WORD.

input = 'faefae+faefae':

> line 1:0 mismatched input 'faefae+faefae' expecting WORD.

Last input should work, why doesn't it?

Help is much appreciated,
wish you all a nice day!

Comment: That's weird. The 3rd example should have worled, and the 2nd one should have emitted a different error message. Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`faefae+faefae` will parse just fine.

You probably haven't regenerated the lexer/parser classes.

With IntelliJ and the ANTLR4 plugin, I get this:

[image]